# Does CATCH exception gets reported to Firebase/Fabric etc?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, try-catch, reporting

Does **CATCH** exception gets reported to Firebase/Fabric etc? 
If I leave catch block empty (for some reason IDK why someone does it), android gives warning but naming its variable **ignored** resolves warning, HOW?

```
try {
      } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
```

Is there any better way to have a centralized exception handler which only works for Debug.
Thanks for your time and effort in advance.

Comment: 1. A catch cannot possibly get reported. 2. Your IDE is letting you off the warning because you are communicating that the exception should be ignored. 3. Don't use empty catch blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, So naming variable IGNORED my IDE is considering its ignored? Does it have some kind of predefined word? (I am using Android Studio)

Comment: android studio skips the warning when the variable named as `ignored`. that's it nothing else. (yes it's predefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my finds so far (correct me if you disagree)

1. Renaming the exception variable to ***ignored***
      From many references and searching, the concept of naming variable to 
      ignored was introduced after developer community did it too often. Some 
      of the references are: [Style Guide](http://sportngin.github.io/styleguide/android.html), [Android Source](https://source.android.com/setup/code-style), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/2so5tu/mildly_amusing_intellij_suggests_to_rename_a/)
2. Adding a comment in catch block ***//empty***
      As I talked about spending time to search about it, New finding is adding 
      a comment to catch block also does the same trick of understanding catch 
      block is left empty on volunteer.

Finally recommended is to make a logger class or use default loggers to log exception rather than leaving empty.

Thanks to @khelwood for helping.